# Finding Supremum and Infimum of a given set. Is my solution correct?

Tags: real-analysis

Question: Let $ S = { (m-n)/(mn) : m, n \in  N} $. Find, with proof, $ \inf S $ and $\sup S$ .

My Solution (Rough draft): Just from looking at this formula I feel that perhaps to achieve the largest element possible from the set, it would be of the form $m-1/m$ and the it would follow that the smallest would follow as $1-n/n$ if it was the case the $n=1$ and $m=1$ respectively.

I suppose I would first have to show that they are upper and lower bounds respectively. I don't know how to show that $m-1/m \ge \forall k \in S$ and that $1-n/n \le \forall k \in S$.

As for showing that these are indeed the supremum and infimum:
If we assume that they are indeed upper and lower bounds respectively and if we take an arbitrary upper bound $k$ and $j \in S$ such that $k\ge\forall j \in S$ and that $k < m-1/m$, from which follows that  $km+1<m$. From this we can say that since we assumed $k$ is an upper bound that is less than $m-1/m$ as an upperbound, we can see that it is false that $km+1<m$. So it would follow that $m-1/m$ is the least upperbound and therefore $\sup \ S = m-1/m$. I would follow the same logic to get that $\inf \ S = 1-n/n$.

This is not homework. I am studying for an exam. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The infimum/supremum should *not* depend on $n,m$. Btw. the answer is $\inf S=-1$, $\sup S=1$.

Comment: If you write the elements of $S$ as $\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m}$, the answer becomes much easier to see.

Comment: I actually did as you guys said. I ended up having to use the Archimedean Property to show that there is indeed no upperbound less than 1 and greater than -1. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The set $S$ can instead be written as those numbers of the form $\frac1n-\frac1m,$ where $m,n\in\Bbb N.$ This set has neither maximum or minimum. In general, $m-\frac1m$ *is* an upper bound--except when $m=1$--but isn't the least such. For example, $x<\frac43<m-\frac1m$ for all $x\in S$ and all integers $m>1.$

Note that for all $m,n\in\Bbb N,$ we have $$\frac1n-1\le\frac1n-\frac1m\le1-\frac1m.$$ Since $\frac1n-1,1-\frac1m\in S$ for all $m,n\in\Bbb N,$ it suffices to find the least upper bound of the numbers $1-\frac1m$ and greatest lower bound of the numbers $\frac1n-1.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the set is $S = \{ {1 \over n } - {1 \over m} | m,n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Hence if $x \in S$, then $-x \in S$ and since $\inf S = - \sup -S$, we see that $\inf S = - \sup S$, so we need only compute one of these.

Clearly ${1 \over n} \le 1$ for all $n$, so ${1 \over n } - {1 \over m} \le 1- {1 \over m} \le 1$ for all $m,n$. Hence $1$ is an upper bound. Furthermore, for any $\epsilon>0$, if ${1 \over m} < \epsilon$, we have $1-{1\over m} > 1 - \epsilon$, hence $1$ is the least upper bound, that is $\sup S = 1$.